# Cómo llamar desde otra librería una función cuyo prototipo y definición están dentro de otro archivo .c

Tags: c, funciones, prototipos, stm32

cómo están?. Tengo un problema con la librería que estoy usando para hacer mi proyecto en C, el fabricante del microcontrolador STM32 que estoy usando hizo que la configuración automática de su IDE meta tanto el prototipo como la definición de una función estén dentro de un archivo **.c** específico, esa función convierte un número decimal en uno con formato BDC y no quiero reescribirla, como ejemplo están así dentro del archivo **.c** de origen, prototipo en la primera línea y definición en las líneas siguientes del ejemplo que coloqué, en realidad están a cientos de líneas de distancia en el mismo archivo .c pero para el ejemplo sirve

```
static uint8_t            RTC_ByteToBcd2(uint8_t Value);

/**
  * @brief  Converts a 2 digit decimal to BCD format.
  * @param  Value: Byte to be converted
  * @retval Converted byte
  */
static uint8_t RTC_ByteToBcd2(uint8_t Value)
{
uint32_t bcdhigh = 0U;
while (Value >= 10U)
{
    bcdhigh++;
    Value -= 10U;
}
return ((uint8_t)(bcdhigh << 4U) | Value);
}
```

esta función la quiero llamar desde otro archivo **.c** el cual ya tengo creado donde recibo unos datos por interfaz I2C y los asigno en una función, aunque la función es sencilla no la quiero reescribir sino que quiero usar lo ya creado y de esa forma me evito líneas de código adicionales, el problema es que no se como incluir el archivo donde se encuentra prototipada y definida la función ya que el compilador me dice lo siguiente cuando intento incluir el archivo **.c**

```
fatal error: stm32f1xx_hal_rtc.c: No such file or directory mensaje.c   /Esclava/Core/Src   line 10 C/C++ Problem
```

Cómo podría resolver esto sin reescribir la función?, de esa manera me evito el tener que enviar los datos en formato BCD desde el transmisor.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada.

Comment: ¿Por qué definiste la función como estática? Esto quiere decir, que la función solo será visible en el archivo fuente donde se definió. Lo que debes hacer, es que la función `RTC_ByteToBcd2` sea externa y así lo podrás usar en otros archivos de origen y por cierto, cada archivo .c debe tener su correspondiente cabecera (con extensión .h), ahí es donde debes de añadir el prototipo de la función y sí lo quieres usar en otro archivo fuente, simplemente lo incluyes con la directiva `#include`.

Comment: Yo no la definí así, la definió el fabricante

Comment: No podrás usar la función `RTC_ByteToBcd2` porque es *estática*. Debes eliminar el *static* y agregar el prototipo en el **.h** y luego recompila la librería.

Comment: Gracias @MrDave1999, esa es la respuesta pero, aunque tu comentario es la respuesta correcta preferí simplemente definir otra función que hace lo mismo en otra librería. Si pones ese comentario como respuesta, te califico como la mejor respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente, incluye ese archivo C como si fuera un *header*, al principio de tu propio archivo:

```
#include <ByteToBcd2.c>

/*
    Mis funciones
*/
...
```

Puedes tener problemas con la ruta. Una opción **segura** es copiar ese archivo al directorio en el que se encuentren tus propios archivos `.c`, y usar

```
#include "ByteToBcd2.c"
```

con comillas, en lugar de águlos.

Tendrás que hacer ese `#include` en cada uno de tus archivos que lo usen.

Por último, al compilar, no es necesario que hagas referencia a dicho archivo. Compila y enlaza solo tus propios archivos `.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta lo mejor de mi conocimiento, debes incluir ese archivo .c entre los archivos que pasas al llamar a gcc para *tu* archivo c (si es que estás usando gcc... para otros compiladores supongo que funciona igual).

Comment: estoy usando el STM32Cube IDE el cual usa ARMCC la cual creo es una variación del gcc para usar con los micros STM32, ya intenté incluirlo y me da el error mencionado más arriba, de todas maneras la función está definida como estática y no la puedo modificar porque la usan muchas más funciones internas del API, como que me toca hacer una por fuera

Comment: Creo que weris útil que en la pregunte coloques la llamada al compilador con sus parámetros y el mensaje de error.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que declarar las funciones en un `.h` y definirlas en el `.c`. Compilas el `.c` a una libreria. Luego inlcuyes el `.h` en tu codigo, y le das instrucciones al linker de que use la libreria. No conozco el compilador con el que estas trabajando, pero estos pasos son lo que se hace por lo general. De seguro que con la idea general de que es lo que hay que hacer puedes hacer el resto

Comment: Esas son funciones internas del API, el desarrollador (ST) las definió así. Yo lo que estaba haciendo era tratar de usar sus funciones para no escribir más código.